# why i am getting Error when modify table column clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table with column action `LowCardinality(String)`,
but I want to change this column to -> action `Nullable(String)` and I am getting this error:

> Code: 473, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: READ locking attempt on
> "glassbox.beacon_event" has timed out! (120000ms) Possible deadlock
> avoided. Client should retry.: While executing Columns (version
> 20.4.2.9 (official build))

Also the client is stuck (tabix).

If i will run this command like this, it works:

```
alter table test modify column action  String

alter table test modify column action Nullable(String)
```

Why can't I run with one command?

```
alter table test modify column action Nullable(String)
```

Comment: what CH version do you use?

Comment: I AM USING 20.4.2

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it on 20.4.2.9. Could you provide more details - table schema, the error message with the callstack (call *clickhouse-client* with param *--stacktrace*)?

Answer (score 1):

probably it's a bug. Try Ch version 20.6